# Creating/Uploading new file at Google Cloud Storage bucket using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

How to create new empty files in Google Cloud Storage using Python with client libraries available?

Or how to upload a new file to a selected bucket using blob function "upload_from_filename()" ? To initialize the blob object we should have file already in the cloud bucket, but I want to create a new file name, and copy the content from the file stored locally. I want to do this using python.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you need to load the library

```
import google.cloud.storage
```

Assuming you have a service account created and JSON file loaded somewhere, you need to create a client object

```
storage_client = google.cloud.storage.Client.from_service_account_json('JSON filepath')
```

Then you need to provide the bucket object

```
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
```

Now define the path within your bucket and the file name

```
d = 'path/name'
```

The **blob** method creates the new file, also an object.

```
d = bucket.blob(d)
```

The **upload_from_string** method add the contents of the file. There are other methods allowing you to perform different tasks.

```
d.upload_from_string('V')
```

The first few steps take the longest to be ready the first time.

Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly on the first try

Comment: What if I want to upload a list of files?

Comment: I have been using a loop, uploading one file at a time.

Answer (score 8):

If somebody is looking for the same thing, here is the solution. First you need to create/initialize bucket variable with the bucket name you want to create a new blob in. After that instead of calling blob you create blob using bucket.blob("filename"), this creates a new blob if the given filename is not there in the bucket already. Then you can use blob.create_from_filename("filename_which_you want to copy"), this will copy the contents to the blob created earlier for more detail solution you can read blob documentation here:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html

Hope this will help someone. Below is the sample python code:

```
client=storage.Client();  
bucket=client.get_bucket('your bucket name');  
blob=bucket.blob('newfile you want to create')
blob.upload_from_filename('localdirectory/filename.mp4')
```

Comment: It generates: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'

Comment: Hi jack, 
Sorry for late response! Are you able to atleast import storage package("from google.cloud import storage")?

Please share more details about the code. You can also go through the documentation here -> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: Important for me was also to specify the content type and timeout:

`blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, timeout=None, content_type="video/mp4")`