# How to associate a GCS bucket with actual GCS filesystem resource?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket

How does one associate a bucket with an actual GCS folder/file?  I see that one creates buckets, then registers clients to access it, but not seeing how that bucket creation is associated to the actual filesystem resource...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating/Uploading new file at Google Cloud Storage bucket using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264664/creating-uploading-new-file-at-google-cloud-storage-bucket-using-python)

Comment: Can you describe what you name 'GCS file system"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct, this would be an answer

```
gs://bucket/folder/subfolder/file"
```

Comment: How does this map into the GCS example?
def create_bucket_class_location(bucket_name):
    """Create a new bucket in specific location with storage class"""
    # bucket_name = "your-new-bucket-name"
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.storage_class = "COLDLINE"
    new_bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket, location="us")
    print(        "Created bucket {} in {} with storage class {}".format(
            new_bucket.name, new_bucket.location, new_bucket.storage_class
        )
    )
    return new_bucket

Comment: I believe these two documents [1][2][3] will answer to your questions. Where the first document [1] shares code snippet about how to create a Cloud Storage bucket, the second one [2] describes how to upload a file to GCS bucket and this doc [3] describes copying objects. There you can see how to associate a GCS bucket with Objects. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-python
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python
[3] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy